# angular chartjs not showing data properly

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, angular6

I'm using Angular 6 and trying to implement a Chart.js line chart. Basically, I'm calling my API for two arrays: a `weight_data` array and a `weight_date` array and using them for the chart.

I store the arrays I got from the API request in two instances: `this.weight_date` and `this.weight_data`.

Here's the code for the chart:

```
//   code for chart here
this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: this.weight_date, // your labels array
    datasets: [
      {
        data: this.weight_data, // your data array
        borderColor: '#e0573a',
        fill: true
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true
      }],
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Weight Tracker',
      fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
      fontColor: '#272727',
      fontSize: 18,
      padding: 12
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
          left: 10,
          right: 20,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
      }
    },
    gridLines: {
      drawOnChartArea: true
    },
  }
});
```

It's works okay when I use pre-coded arrays (`["11/02/18", "11/03/18", "11/04/18"]` for dates and `[65, 66, 67]` for weight). But when I try to use the two instances, the chart comes up blank. There's no error of sorts, it's just blank.

I'm doing the API call first then initializing the chart, respectively, in `ngOnInit`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the data before initializing the chart? Retrieving the data will be asynchronous, and should therefore probably be handled by subscribing to an observable.

Comment: @JeffFohl I see, this might be the case. But would you mind posting your solution on how to construct the observable below?

Comment: Sure - see below for a simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what I was doing wrong: I'm using axios, which is promise-based, so taking @JeffFhol's suggestion into account, my two instances were blank since I was initializing the chart at the same time I was making the API request.

The solution was to initialize the chart in the `then` clause of the axios request, which ensures that my instances aren't empty.

Here's the snippet that worked:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'url_to_api',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
     // custom data headers, etc.
  },
  data: {
    // data to be sent
  }
})
.then(response => {
  this.weight_dates = response.data.weight_date;
  this.weight_data = response.data.weight_data;

  //   code for chart here
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to subscribe to an observable which can provide the data, and once it comes in, you can then initialize your chart. Usually, we would want to have the HTTP call occur within a service, but to simplify, this is how we could do with within a component:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


export class MyChart implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private getData() {
    let url = '[SOME-URL]' // your path to the data API endpoint
    return this.http.get(url) as Observable<Array<any>>; // you would want to use correct typings here, instead of <any>
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      // assign your data here, and then initialize your chart.
    });
  }
}
```